# How to destroy test module in NestJS?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript, typeorm, nestjs

I really cant get into testing world. I'm trying to write some simple tests to get started. Here is my test:

```
describe('UsersController', () => {
  let usersController: UsersController;
  let usersService: UsersService;
  let module = null;
  let connection: Connection;

  beforeEach(async () => {
      module = await Test.createTestingModule({
        modules: [DatabaseModule, LibrariesModule],
        controllers: [UsersController],
        components: [UsersService, ...usersProviders],
      })
      // TODO: provide testing config here instead of separate .env.test file
      // .overrideComponent(constants.config)
      // .useValue()
        .compile();
      connection = module.select(DatabaseModule).get(constants.DBConnectionToken);
      usersService = module.get(UsersService);
      usersController = module.get(UsersController);
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  describe('getAllUsers', () => {
    it('should return an array of users', async () => {
      const result = [];

      expect(await usersController.getAllUsers())
        .toEqual([]);
    });
  });

  describe('createUser', () => {
    it('should create a user with valid credentials', async () => {
      const newUser: CreateUserDto = {
        email: 'mail@userland.com',
        password: 'password',
        name: 'sample user',
      };
      const newUserId = '123';
      jest.spyOn(usersService, 'createUser').mockImplementation(async () => ({user_id: newUserId}));
      const res = await usersController.createUser(newUser);
      expect(res)
        .toEqual( {
          user_id: newUserId,
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Problems start when i'm trying to create new testing module (it happens every time before each test) , typeorm complaining about still active database connection (after first test):

```
Cannot create a new connection named "default", because connection with such name already exist and it now has an active connection session.
```

By the way, how i can delete all records from the database after each test?

Comment: ...by removing added records and closing a connection?

Comment: its very bad route for me.

Comment: Well, it's the only one if you're using real DB. Most times unit testing presumes that you mock everything but tested unit.

Comment: Im using MongoDB, so there no transactions, and thats very bad.

Comment: Tests shouldn't affect existing DB, there should be a dedicated DB for tests that can be dropped any moment. But again, this applies to e2e tests. For unit tests it doesn't make sense to use real DB. Mock everything but a controller.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `close()` the application before you create a new one with the same database connection. You can clear the database by calling `synchronize(true)`.

```
import { getConnection } from 'typeorm';

afterEach(async () => {
  if (module) {
    // drop database
    await getConnection().synchronize(true);
    // close database connections
    await module.close();
  }
});
```

---

As an alternative, you can also allow `typeorm` to reuse an existing database connection by setting `keepConnectionAlive`. (You probably want to do this only in tests, e.g. by checking `process.env.NODE_ENV`.)

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  // ...
  keepConnectionAlive: true
})
```